# Have for loop script do something only every Nth iteration

Tags: matlab, for-loop, iteration

In MATLAB (or more generally) if I wanted something to happen only, for example, every 50 iterations of a `for loop` how could I do this better than below? That is to not write out every possible value of *+50*.  Thanks.

```
for i = 1:1060;
    if i = 50 || 100 || 150 || ... || 1050
        randi(i); % for example, just do something
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't know the MATLAB syntax, but you are looking for the modulus (remainder after division) function: E.g. `if i mod 50 = 0` ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is

```
if mod(i, 50) == 0
  do something
```

Comment: I changed your answer (+1) to Matlab syntax (since it is a Matlab question), hope that's okay. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is

```
for i = 0:50:1050
    do_stuff(i);
end
```

unless, it is unclear from your question, if the previous answer is what you really want, which you might need in the case that looks like this

```
for i = 1:1060
    if mod(i, 50) == 0
        do_something(i)
    end
    do_something_else(i)
end
```

Cheers,--